# bash script stuck in loop?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I made a quick little script with the limited bash scripting knowledge I have. It has a function with a flag that takes an argument.

like so:

> switchall -b branchesIwantToCheckOut

```
# Git switch all repos to a given branch.
switchall() {
    # Reset OPTIND so we can call this function multiple times.
    local OPTIND

    while getopts "b:" OPTION; do
        case $OPTION in
            b)
                echo "Switching all GIT repo's to: $OPTARG"
                for d in ~/git/*/ 
                do
                    ( cd $d && git checkout $OPTARG )
                done
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

The problem with this is that whenever I run it my CPU usage increases immensely to the point where I will be hitting 70% when I view **top** after multiple uses. I'm guessing I messed up the loop somehow but I don't know how exactly.

If somebody could take a quick loop to help me out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Theres no limit on the loop, so it will use as much cpu as possible until it is  complete. Add a sleep in it if it's bothering you.

Comment: It seems to persist even after it has done it's job though, that is my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works for me :/

Comment: Which process is using CPU after this script has exited?

Comment: Debug with steps. Add `sleep 1` and `echo "next $d"` in your for-loop and see where it loops unexpected.

Comment: @123: I disagree; there **are** limits. First, for each invocation of the shell function *switchall*, assuming that the OP really invoked it in the way he stated, the `while` loop is performed only once, simply because after the first option is processed, getopts returns a status code greater than zero. The inner loop is executed for each entry in the *git* directory, so, technically, there is no limit, but since the command in the loop body is not executed in the background, the git checkouts are done sequentially. This might take time, but would not explain the increase in CPU consumption.

Comment: @Stephan-v: Are you executing this shell function from the command line (i.e. is it a shell function defined in your .bashrc), or are you calling it from within another shell script?

Comment: @user1934428 I meant limits on execution speed, it would use 100% cpu if the disk or anything else wasn't a bottleneck. For example try `while :;do :;done &`, and you will see it uses all available cpu.

Comment: @user1934428 from the commandline, so far I am pretty baffled.

Comment: @Stephan-v: If it is from the command line, it's easy: Place a "sleep 2" in the line after the while (so you have a chance to intervene), and do a `set -x` before you call the script, and observe what happens.

Comment: And, for general sanity, I would also catch the default case, if an incorrection option is supplied.